# android: Google online translate speaking

Tags: android, translation, text-to-speech

With reference to [Using Arabic characters with google TTS API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220324/using-arabic-characters-with-google-tts-api), I have tried the following:

### Code:

```
public void button_star_click(View view) 
{

    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);  

    String Abc = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=zh-cn&q=你好嗎";
    try 
    {
        player.setDataSource(Abc);
    } 
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();} 
    catch (SecurityException e) {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();} 
    catch (IllegalStateException e) {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();} 
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    try 
    {
        player.prepare();
    } 
    catch (IllegalStateException e) {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();} 
    catch (IOException e) {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
    player.start(); 
}
```

### Logcat:

```
10-20 00:59:27.190: D/GestureDetector(11559): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0
10-20 00:59:27.190: D/MediaPlayer Datasource XXXX(11559): The datasource is: http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=zh-cn&q=你好嗎
10-20 00:59:27.190: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(11559): native_setup
10-20 00:59:27.190: V/MediaPlayer(11559): constructor
10-20 00:59:27.195: V/MediaPlayer(11559): setListener
10-20 00:59:27.195: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(11559): setAudioStreamType: 3
10-20 00:59:27.195: V/MediaPlayer(11559): MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
10-20 00:59:27.200: V/MediaPlayer(11559): setVideoSurfaceTexture
10-20 00:59:27.200: V/MediaPlayer(11559): prepare
10-20 00:59:27.275: V/MediaPlayer(11559): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-1004
10-20 00:59:27.275: E/MediaPlayer(11559): error (1, -1004)
10-20 00:59:27.275: V/MediaPlayer(11559): signal application thread
10-20 00:59:27.275: V/MediaPlayer(11559): prepare complete - status=1
10-20 00:59:27.280: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(11559): start
10-20 00:59:27.280: V/MediaPlayer(11559): start
10-20 00:59:27.280: E/MediaPlayer(11559): start called in state 0
10-20 00:59:27.280: V/MediaPlayer(11559): message received msg=100, ext1=-38, ext2=0
10-20 00:59:27.280: E/MediaPlayer(11559): error (-38, 0)
10-20 00:59:27.280: V/MediaPlayer(11559): callback application
10-20 00:59:27.280: V/MediaPlayer(11559): back from callback
10-20 00:59:27.290: E/MediaPlayer(11559): Error (-38,0)
```

### Question:

Once the button is clicked, no sounds are output.

I have tried [http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=zh-hk&q=你好嗎](http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=zh-hk&q=%E4%BD%A0%E5%A5%BD%E5%97%8E) and it is also working ok.

I have tried implementing TTS but seems TTS just supports english, german, french and 2 other languages, in total 5 languages only without Cantonese or Chinese.

Are there anybody could advise what is wrong with the above codes?
Many thanks!

Comment: print the exception in catch block..

Comment: thanks for your response. logcat added

Answer (score 0):

You can try download the media first and then play it.